# Gmail emails with images get stuck in outbox for 1-2 days

Tags: gmail, email, attachments

*Android 11; Samsung Galaxy A20; Gmail app (fully updated):*

When I send an email that has an image, the email gets stuck in the Gmail outbox folder (status = Queued) for a day or two before eventually being sent.

Details:

1. This issue started a couple of weeks ago. The Gmail app worked fine before then -- ever since I got the phone years ago. I'm not aware of any changes that were made to my phone/settings that might have caused this issue.
2. The issue happens no matter what the file size is -- not just for large photos. For example, a screenshot of a small area of the screen also has this issue.
3. The network type is a cell data plan, not Wi-Fi. Although switching to Wi-Fi doesn't solve the issue either.
4. I tried resetting the Gmail app by un-updating the app (can't uninstall the app), then re-updating the app. That had no effect. I also cleared the app cache and data.
5. The issue happens regardless of the email recipient.
6. I don't have this problem when sending emails that have no attachments.

---

Why are emails with attachments not being sent right away?

Comment: GMail app allows to use GMail as well as IMAP accounts from other mail servers. What mail account is your question about?

Comment: @Robert It’s a Gmail account. I.e. xxxx@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer as to why it's happening. But I did come up with a couple of workarounds:

1. Sometimes works: Refresh the outbox folder in Gmail by using the *drag-down* motion.
2. Always works: Send the email from the Gmail website in a browser instead of using the Gmail app.